Applications of Signature of 4k Dimensional Manifold?
Algebraic topology finds many applications outside of pure math. For instance, differential forms (at least 0- and 1-forms) find applications in engineering thermodynamics. The state of a thermodynamic system is specified by two independent, intensive variables (say, specific enthalpy $h$ and pressure $p$). One has a heat differential 1-form $\delta Q$ (which is not exact and could be written $\omega_Q$) that may be integrated over an oriented, piecewise smooth path $[P]$ or closed curve $[C]$ to produce the heat transfer $\displaystyle \Delta Q = \int_{[P]} \delta Q$ or $\displaystyle \Delta Q = \oint_{[C]} \delta Q$. Similarly, there is an entropy 1-form $\displaystyle d_R S = \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ that "is exact with respect to reversible paths and Carnot cycles" with $\displaystyle \Delta S = \int_{[P]} d_R S$ and $\displaystyle \Delta S = \oint_{[C]} d_R S$ and is used to define the physically-realizable orientations of non-reversible path and non-Carnot cycles.
What would be an actual application outside of pure math of the signature of a manifold? Of course, there's the "internal application to manifold topology" that it may be used to distinguish two manifolds of dimension $n = 4k$ that have their other invariants the same. But, what would be an actual "external application" of this algebraic topology object? Would there be an application of the quadratic form if not the signature itself?
(I guess the signature of a manifold and the Hirzebruch Signature Theorem are many times the last theorems one learns in an algebraic topology course, and it was always a little bit disappointing to me that there were no actual applications of this capstone invariant except to distinguish two manifolds of dimension $n = 4k$ that have their other invariants the same.)
